# The Correct Structure is not showing on Html Display Flex

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styling

I'm a student and I'm working on an HTML project that I need to present. I've uploaded the section I'm having a problem on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bfsunt/pen/BaLGNQK), so you don't need to create a document and save the code from StackOverflow.

I was trying to have a structure like this with flexbox, but I can't get it right, I'm missing something small maybe, can you guys try to help me to fix this one, so the others learn too.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sektori-2 {
  padding-top: 4%;
  background-color: #17181A;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sektori-2v1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.d2 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.d3 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.d4 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.d5 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.wink-sm-title-section-2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.3rem;
  color: white;
}

.wink-title-section-2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.wink-txt-section-2 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.wink-holder-section-2 {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wink-item-title-section-2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.wink-item-txt-section-2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sektori-2">
  <div class="sektori-2v1">
    <p class="wink-sm-title-section-2">ÇKA OFROJM NE?</p>
    <h1 class="wink-title-section-2">Wink, një vend ku mund të gjendet gjithçka inovative.</h1>
    <p class="wink-txt-section-2">Ne jemi të apasionuar pas punës sonë dhe na pëlqen të fuqizojmë aftësitë dixhitale të bizneseve. Nëse edhe ju, ndiheni në tën njëjtën mënyrë dhe mendoni se karriera juaj mund të vazhdojë duke bashkpunuar me ne, atëherë shikojeni shërbimet tona.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="d2">
      <img src="images/edit.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
      <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">Ilustrime</p>
      <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink Illustron gjëra abstrakte në mënyrë profesionale dhe precize me standardet të fundit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d3">
      <img src="images/play.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
      <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">Ilustrime</p>
      <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink mund t'ju nidhmojë në trailerin tuaj animativ duke përdorur dizajn fenomenal.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="d4">
      <img src="images/gallery.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
      <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">Ilustrime</p>
      <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink harton me kreativitet markat e bizneseve të ndryshme duke përdorur veglat e fundit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d5">
      <img src="images/paper.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
      <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">Ilustrime</p>
      <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink harton dhe zhvillon faqet inovative të internetit me përqëndrim te përdorshmëria.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read this article, it will help you a lot about using Flexbox:

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Yep, so did you found the bug?

Comment: @omer-m-fathy the question is that the correct thing is not showing, not that the structure isn't good

Comment: take a look at my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you want based on your code `

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sektori-2 {
  padding-top: 4%;
  background-color: #17181A;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items:flex-end
}

.sektori-2v1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.d1,.d2,.d3,.d4,.d5,.d6{
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.wink-sm-title-section-2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.3rem;
  color: white;
}

.wink-title-section-2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: normal;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.wink-txt-section-2 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
}

.wink-holder-section-2 {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wink-item-title-section-2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.wink-item-txt-section-2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sektori-2">
        <div class="sektori-2v1">
          <p class="wink-sm-title-section-2"></p>
          <h1 class="wink-title-section-2">Wink, një vend ku mund të gjendet gjithçka inovative.</h1>
          <p class="wink-txt-section-2">Ne jemi të apasionuar pas punës sonë dhe na pëlqen të fuqizojmë aftësitë dixhitale të bizneseve. Nëse edhe ju, ndiheni në tën njëjtën mënyrë dhe mendoni se karriera juaj mund të vazhdojë duke bashkpunuar me ne, atëherë shikojeni shërbimet tona.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="d1">
            <img src="images/edit.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
            <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">1</p>
            <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink Illustron gjëra abstrakte në mënyrë profesionale dhe precize me standardet të fundit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="d2">
            <img src="images/edit.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
            <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">2</p>
            <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink Illustron gjëra abstrakte në mënyrë profesionale dhe precize me standardet të fundit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="d3">
            <img src="images/play.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
            <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">3</p>
            <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink mund t'ju nidhmojë në trailerin tuaj animativ duke përdorur dizajn fenomenal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="d4">
            <img src="images/gallery.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
            <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">4</p>
            <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink harton me kreativitet markat e bizneseve të ndryshme duke përdorur veglat e fundit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="d5">
            <img src="images/paper.svg" alt="Icon" width="42px">
            <p class="wink-item-title-section-2">5</p>
            <p class="wink-item-txt-section-2">Wink harton dhe zhvillon faqet inovative të internetit me përqëndrim te përdorshmëria.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

`